Google Sheets Array Error from IF can't have anything in rows below formula
Solved the first problem but one small other one
The code below fixed my error, but I need it to return "Select All" If the drop-down is set to 100% and a student name.
=IF(B31 = "All",
IF(D31 = 'Master Data'!AC1,
FILTER({'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
'Master Data'!AC2:AC <> ""
),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D31, 'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 0)),
FILTER({'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
'Master Data'!AC2:AC = D31
),
"Select a student name"
)
),
IF(B31 = "<100%",
FILTER({'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
('Master Data'!AI2:AI < 1) * (NOT(ISBLANK('Master Data'!AC2:AC)))
),
"Invalid selection for B31"
)
)
I am creating a dashboard in Google Sheets. I have the following formula to filter a list.  Everything is working correctly except.   B31 = "<100%".   When  B31 = "<100%" and D31 is = 'Master Data'!AC1 it will only correctly return if there is nothing in any rows below it for the entire page.  I need to be able to leave the end open as the data could change, and I need to be able to add those new rows of data without having to change the code.  Every other part of this code works fine and returns the list even if something is in the rows below it as long as it is not in the range of the returning values.  I have tried so many workarounds and am a total novice at this.  Help me understand why it is only this part of the code that is returning this error, but the other parts of the code are not affected by the rows below having data.  Can this be fixed?
Sorry, I can't share the sheet as it has student information.
=IF(
    B31 = "All",
    IF(
        D31 = 'Master Data'!AC1,
        FILTER(
            {'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
            'Master Data'!AC2:AC <> ""
        ),
        IF(
            ISNUMBER(MATCH(D31, 'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 0)),
            FILTER(
                {'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
                'Master Data'!AC2:AC = D31
            ),
            "Select a student name"
        )
    ),
    IF(
        B31 = "<100%",
        IF(
            D31 = 'Master Data'!AC1,
            FILTER(
                {'Master Data'!AC2:AC, 'Master Data'!AF2:AF, 'Master Data'!AH2:AH, 'Master Data'!AI2:AI},
                'Master Data'!AI2:AI < 1
            ),
            "Select 'All' to filter by student name"
        ),
        "Invalid selection for B31"
    )
)

I have tried multiple ways to fix the code and test that portion of the code with the same results, using lens and helper rows haven't helped and show mismatched rows.  Even the most basic version to filter for <100% creates the same problem.
Here is a link to my spreadsheet.  The code is on the first page.  The third section down on the left under Quarterly Attendance.  The two drop down are All/100% and Student name/List of Names.  The second page is the Master data page which pulls information from other pages that will have data from downloaded spreadsheets that will change. I am not in control of the data I will download, so this is workaround to adapt to header changes/column changes.  Every column on the Data page is linked to a different page, and by changing the first row on the data page, I can adjust which column it pulls from on the page.  I am not sure if any of this is affecting my current code so I thought I would mention it.

is "<100%" plain text? your formula looks okay. there are no errors in syntax. could you set up copy of your sheet with fake data for debugging?

I have created a fake version and added to the original question along with some other details.  Thank you for checking it out.

Solved the first problem but one small other one
See notes in Question.

try:
=LET(r, CHOOSECOLS('Master Data'!AC2:AI,1,4,6,7), n, INDEX(r,,1), p, INDEX(r,,4),
 IFERROR(FILTER(r, IF(B31="All", n<>"", p<1), 
 IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D31, n, )), n=D31, n<>"")), "no data for this selection"))



LET(
  rng,'Master Data'!AC:AI, b,B31, d,D31, 
  array,QUERY(rng, "SELECT AC, AF, AH, AI 
    WHERE AC <> '' OFFSET 1",0),
  ac,INDEX(array,,1), ai,INDEX(array,,4),
  hdr,INDEX(rng,1,1),
  IF(b="All",
    IF(d=hdr, array, IFNA(FILTER(array, ac=d), "Select a student name")),
    IF(b<>"<100%", "Invalid selection for B31",
      IF(d=hdr, FILTER(array, ai<1), "Select 'All' to filter by student name"))))

FILTER  IF  IFNA  INDEX  OFFSET  QUERY
